# Can Groot be killed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, groot

We see in Guardians of the galaxy that he can have his arms servered, shot at and blown up. So can Groot be killed in the Marvel cinematic universe?

Comment: Presumably if you destroy *everything*, yes.

Comment: Yeah, chuck him into a star and he'd be quite quite dead.

Comment: You also probably just prevent anyone form replanting his pieces.

Comment: Not an answer because the animated series is not actually MCU, but Disney XD did a couple origin story shorts for each character leading up to their Guardians of the Galaxy cartoon. [Groot's origins](https://youtu.be/re4QY-rIDCY) show that many of his species are killed by a very large explosion.

Comment: I.. am.. groot.

Comment: @groot Exactly. The answer to the OP's question is "I am Groot" :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Probably. (Spoilers)

Groot was almost completely destroyed in the film.

Rocket had to replant a splinter of him in order for him to regrow.

[image: Baby Groot]

Therefore, if you destroyed every single piece of him, he'd probably be dead for good.

Additionally, the Collector believes that Groot can die.

> The Collector: I never thought I'd meet a Groot. Sir, you must allow me to pay you now so that I may own your carcass. **At the moment of your death**, of course.

Comment: Though the Collector was probably thinking of old age / sickness rather than obliterating every splinter. Wouldn't be much of a collectible item in the later case.

Comment: Also, there is an open question of whether that is really Groot. If you planted several splinters, would you get several Groots?

Comment: @PaulDraper: *we* are Groot.

Comment: I don't think you'd have to destroy every piece.  You would if your goal was to be sure, but blasting him to bits does the job as long as no friend is there to try and revive any pieces.  Just like with pulling a weed or planting a cutting, if it isn't done relatively soon, it's no longer viable.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why not.

Groot is the last of his kind, which presumes that his species was eradicated somehow. I'm not sure if his being the last of his kind is mentioned in the movie so....if we just suppose that he is only an animated plant, he would need water (seen in the movie drinking) and perhaps some other form of nutrient (never seen eating anything else although he does have a mouth), and light.

I don't see why he would be able to survive if placed in a de-humidified room without water, nutrient, or light. If you wanted to be certain, (as some drought resistant plants can be revitalized with water after completely drying out) you could always burn the remains.

Perhaps something as simple as an herbicide might work...

Comment: He's rare, but I don't think there's any mention of being the last of his species.

Comment: @RogueJedi i remember there have been mentions of it. Sorry I don't have specific references, though

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, *but* Groot can survive as long as his head is intact.

According to *Guardians of the Galaxy* trilogy director James Gunn, Groot can survive anything as long as his head is intact. [Gunn confirmed this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/1660352874222862336) when a fan asked him about Groot’s regenerative abilities:

[image: screenshot of tweet]

> **Question:** Just curious could groot grow that fast in 3 because his head was intact or because he didn’t do the light show in Vol 1?

> **James Gunn:** I’m not sure I understand the question - not sure what the light show in Vol 1 is - but as long as Groot’s head is okay he’s okay & remains the same Groot.

Comment: This reminds me of the 2004 Avengers cartoon in which Groot was totally obliterated but still regenerated from nothingness. Of course, it's a different universe.

Answer (score -1):

**Obviously**

His body reacts like most plants, regrowing, producing many offspring, etc.. Like with a tree, the loss of a branch should not cause death. Inhabitable conditions, however could result in failure of bodily functions and death. Also, lack of a food supply or water could kill the plant-like being.

Comment: Counterpoint: a normal humans body reacts very similarly to a Skrulls in many situations, however a human cannot shape shift. The point being that just because 2 organisms exhibit similar properties, we cannot assume that all traits (mortality included) are shared.

Comment: Or perhaps a better (and closer to home) example would be bacteria. Some can handle extreme temperatures, some extreme pressure, some are even [effectively immortal].(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_immortality)

Comment: Then maybe this question has no real answer because no one is qualified to define Groot's biological disposition. It can only be inferred.

Comment: I completely agree. It falls under the "We don't have enough info YET" category. There is a tiny bit more to go on from the comics, but on the whole none of the characters from Guardians of the Galaxy have been fleshed out very well, MCU or otherwise. If I remember correctly, that was the idea. The creators wanted to bring a bunch of obscure characters from the 70's and 80's together and do something awesome with them. [Will provide source when I'm at my computer.]

Answer (score -1):

**NO**

According to the [Guardians cartoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(TV_series)) that came after the first movie.

In the [Groot origins episode](http://guardiansofthegalaxy.marvelkids.com/videos/groot-origins-pt-2) as long as Groot is alive there is hope for his entire species.

Dont know what kind of canon this falls under but the cartoons are still being produced and I guess they will tie in with the next movie somehow.

Comment: How does this at all show that it is physically impossible to kill groot?